# Insert availability when one replica is down in a shard

Tags: clickhouse

In a setup with 2 replicas per shard without `insert_quorum` enabled, if one replica goes down, seems the other available replica can keep taking inserts. But is there anything that can block inserts in the future? For example when there are X unreplicated inserts, then stop taking in more inserts for a given shard?

Comment: No such feature

Comment: @DenisZhuravlev Got it, but I thought CH would first replicate data parts before merging. In this case, the data parts will be unmergable since replication is failing and that would eventually cause too many parts in the table? I guess that is one way to cause insert failures after one replica down for some time?

Comment: No. It won't be a problem. Live replica does not wait for a dead replica. Live replica does merges and writes logs about merges and new parts (merged) into ZK. When a dead replica became live back it tries to re-play log and downloads or initial 0-level parts and merge them or downloads already merged parts, in case if initial parts already removed. Moreover replicas don't not know about other replicas and don't care. They only care about a leader because the leader schedules merges but the dead replica cannot be the leader. Because if the leader dies another (live) replica became the leader.

Comment: What about when there is a network partition between the 2 replicas. Say replica1 and replica2 can both talk to ZK, but replica1 and replica2 can not talk to each other. Would this cause too many parts issue?

Comment: >Would this cause too many parts issue

Yes. And it because parts have to be merged in an order of they inserted for data consistency (especially for CollapsingMT)

Comment: And because a leader schedules a merge of all parts listed in ZK.